# NodeJS, Mongoose math operation in UpdateMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

**Hello All**,

I'm actually coding a web application (Angular + NodeJs + MongoDB) with a system of posts.
Each user, can like, comment, reply to others comments  and share the post.
(It's like on a social network).

PostSchema

```
   author : {
       type : String,
       required : true,
   },
   text : {
       type : String,
       max : 1800
   },
   visibility : {
       type : String,
       required : true
   },
   type : {
       type : String,
       required : true
   },
   likes : {
       type : [String],
       default : []
   },
   comments : {
    type : [],
    default : []
},
shareBy : {
    type : [String],
    default : []
},
pictures : {
    type : String
},
trendIndicator : {
    type : String,
    default : 999
}
}, { timestamps : true});
```

Exemple in DB

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("623ca84ffc4cff9c4ea0faa7"),
  author: '623b95047cf1a734d9b965bb',
  text: 'test post 2 full\n',
  visibility: 'Public',
  type: 'Add new Post',
  likes: [ 'Gregoire' ],
  comments: [
    {
      author: '623b95047cf1a734d9b965bb',
      text: 'comment',
      createdAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:19.127Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:19.127Z',
      likes: [Array],
      comments: [],
      picture: [],
      link: ''
    },
    {
      author: '623b95047cf1a734d9b965bb',
      text: 'comment',
      createdAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:21.834Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:21.834Z',
      likes: [Array],
      comments: [],
      picture: [],
      link: ''
    },
    {
      author: '623b95047cf1a734d9b965bb',
      text: 'comment',
      createdAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:24.384Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:24.384Z',
      likes: [Array],
      comments: [],
      picture: [],
      link: ''
    },
    {
      author: '623b95047cf1a734d9b965bb',
      text: 'comment',
      createdAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:26.687Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:26.687Z',
      likes: [Array],
      comments: [],
      picture: [],
      link: ''
    },
    {
      author: '623b95047cf1a734d9b965bb',
      text: 'add a comment',
      createdAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:29.289Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-03-24T17:20:29.289Z',
      likes: [Array],
      comments: [],
      picture: [],
      link: ''
    },
    {
      author: '623b95047cf1a734d9b965bb',
      text: 'reply',
      createdAt: '2022-03-24T17:52:35.552Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-03-24T17:52:35.552Z',
      likes: [Array],
      comments: [],
      picture: [],
      link: ''
    }
  ],
  shareBy: [],
  trendIndicator: '1325',
  createdAt: 2022-03-23T17:20:15.256Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-03-24T18:11:10.872Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

The goal is : In the main page, you can see all the posts and post are sorted by Trends.

What I want to do is : launch from the back one function every X times (with a setTimeOut()) to update all post.trendIndicator

I know we can do this with mongoose with : model.updateMany{filter, update, option}
So I need to do : model.updateMany{{}, update) to updateAll.

But the operation for update the field is very complex.. And I can't find a solution to do this. So for the moment I do this (because I don't have a lot of datas) but it's not optimised if one day I will have more datas.

If an expert can help me it will be amazing.
Thanks

```
async function manageTrend() {
    try {
        const start = new Date()
        console.log('Start of manage trends' + new Date())
        const allPost = await PostModel.find({})
        for(let post of allPost) {
            const top = 1+post.likes.length+(2*post.comments.length)+(3*post.shareBy)
            let allReply = 0
            const deltaTime = (new Date() - post.createdAt) / 3600 /1000
            for(let com of post.comments) {
                allReply += com.comments + com.likes
            }
            post.trendIndicator = Math.floor(top*top / (deltaTime/168))
            await PostModel.updateOne({_id : post._id}, post) 
        }
        const end = new Date()
        console.log(`End of update trends in ${Math.floor((end-start)/60/1000)} mins`)
        setTimeout(manageTrend, 36000)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error when manage trends')
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: To use math and conditional operations using the document fields, and then update - use the [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) feature. This allows to use the Aggregation Operators within the update.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I have try with no success... Can you show me an exemple to show how to do this with my current operation ?